# How to add a group to the sysadmin fixed server role in SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

How can i add a group to the **sysadmin** fixed server role in SQL Server 2008 R2?

> See my [related question](https://serverfault.com/questions/346525/cannot-login-to-sql-server-2008-r2-with-windows-authentication) for details step-by-step screenshots detailing showing that you're not allowed to add groups to the sysadmin role.

### Background information

Before SQL Server 2008 R2, members of the local `Administrators` group were automatically added to the **sysadmin** fixed server role. Starting with SQL Server 2008 R2 that group is no longer added. The new [recommended mechanism is to](http://www.appsecinc.com/resources/top10-database-security-issues/Extensive-User-Group-Privileges/a-BUILTIN-Administrators-member-of-SYSADMIN-fixed-server-role.shtml):

> ...create a separate Windows group containing the appropriate DBAs and
>   grant that group the sysadmin role in the database.

How do i "*grant a Windows group the **sysadmin** role*"?

### See also

- [Adding a Member to a Predefined Role (SQL2000)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905184%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

  > ...users who are members of the BUILTIN\Administrators group are members of the sysadmin fixed server role automatically.
- [Server-Level Roles (SQL2008R2)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188659.aspx)
- [BUILTIN\Administrators member of SYSADMIN fixed server role](http://www.appsecinc.com/resources/top10-database-security-issues/Extensive-User-Group-Privileges/a-BUILTIN-Administrators-member-of-SYSADMIN-fixed-server-role.shtml)

### Related questions

- [Cannot add a *user* to sysadmin role in SQL Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/346525/cannot-login-to-sql-server-2008-r2-with-windows-authentication) (*you can't*)
- [How to add sysadmin to user in SQL Server 2008 when no sysadmin accounts exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921702/how-to-add-sysadmin-to-user-in-sql-server-2008-when-no-sysadmin-accounts-exist) (*reinstall*)
- [MS SQL Server 2005 server role problem](https://serverfault.com/questions/102438/ms-sql-2005-server-role-problem)
- [SQL Server 2005 Accidentally removed a user from public role, can't add user back into role](https://serverfault.com/questions/148344/sql-2k5-accidentally-removed-a-user-from-public-role-cant-add-user-back-into-r)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated, SQL 2008 R2 no longer adds the administrators group as a SQL login by default.  You first have to add the Administrators group as a SQL Server principal.

```
CREATE LOGIN [BUILTIN\Administrators] FROM WINDOWS
```

(or see [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx) for more information on how to add a login)

You can then add that group to the sysadmin role.

```
sp_addsrvrolemember
    @LogiName='BUILTIN\Administrators',
    @RoleName='sysadmin'
```

Comment: Oi vay. i don't have edit permissions. Can you wrap `[BUILTIN\Administrators]` in `[square brackets`]. Otherwise you get *incorrect syntax near '\'*

Comment: Oh, cripes.  I did mean to put that in there....  Sorry boss!